# An abstraction of matrices that can be added, inverted, transposed, multiplied

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, terminology, quadratics, matrix-equations

$$x^TAx+x^Tb+c=(x-h)^TA(x-h)+k$$
where
$$h=-(A+A^T)^{-1}b$$
$$k=c-h^TAh$$

Determining $h$ and $k$ above is called "completing the square" and requires matrix addition, inversion, transposition, multiplication etc.

I am implementing algorithms (such as the above and others) in a generic way such that they can apply to *any* entity on which the requisite operations (addition, inversion, etc.) are defined.

I would call this library "matrix algebra" but I wondered whether there is a more abstract/generic name for "something that can be added, inverted, transposed, multiplied, etc.")?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like $*$-algebras. Nevertheless, the name 'matrix algebra' is a good name.

Answer (score -2):

Yes this would be an example of geometric algebra. A matrix is just a representation of general algebraic /geometric objects like vectors, multivectors, dual multivectors etc..

Comment: This should be a comment. Furthermore, [what is a matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/630676/721644)

Comment: P.S. nisam downvoteala. (:

Comment: Well the op says he is looking for algorithms for calculating these things. A think saying *algebra is not a good answer or comment in this case, don't think there are such general algorithms that would work. So I gave him an answer that's still quite abstract yet concrete in terms of computation.

Comment: I don't see why it should be a comment if it answers the question

Comment: And I think a matrix is what it is. Some set if rows and columns of numbers used to represent something, usually a linear operator..

Comment: Neznam nevolim matrice, mozda Sam previse puta gledao film:)